# customize the body of the autoresponder email

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I have to customize the body of the autoresponder email in Contact Form 7.
As I have one dropdown on the form, on the basis of dropdown I have to update the autoresponder content in the mail.

For the main email I am doing like this

```
$mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' );
$mail['body']= "CUSTOM BODY TEXT";
$contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );
```

Please tell me how to update the auto responder mail

Comment: Unfortunately, questions exclusively regarding 3rd party plugins is [considered to be off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and better asked using [their respective support methods](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7/). Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use mail_2 instead of mail

```
$mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail_2' );
$mail['body']= "CUSTOM BODY TEXT";
$contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail_2' => $mail ) );
```